# Vertical positioning the tooltip in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, tooltip

I am trying to show a tooltip when hovering certian class elements.  The issue is with the vertical positioning.  I want to position it as right center to the hover element, so that the arrow of the tooltip points a hovering element.
The div height varies depending on the hovering class element as i am getting the values from ajax call.  So the position of tool tip is showing differently to each hovering element.  Is there any way to always position it as right center for varying tooltip heights? 
I am not an expert in either Javascript or CSS.  Thanks in advance for your help.

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
    Sys.Application.add_load(function() 
{
            var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll(".URL);
                for (i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
                    temp = nodeList[i].getAttribute("href");
                    if (user[i]) {
                        callURL = baseURL + apiURL + "/" + temp;
                        divTag = document.createElement('div');
                        nodeList[i].appendChild(divTag);
                        divTag.setAttribute("class", "tooltiptext");
                        runAjax1(divTag);
                    }

                }

                function runAjax1(obj1) {
                    $.ajax({
                        success: function(runfeed) {
                            DisplayName = ; //will parse it from ajax respose "runfeed"
                            AccountStatus = ; //will parse it from ajax respose "runfeed"
                            LastLoginDate = ; //will parse it from ajax respose "runfeed"
                            Helptext = '<table><tr>' + '<td id="header" >Name:</td>' + '<td id="value">' + DisplayName + '</td>' + '</tr>' +
                                '<tr>' + '<td id="header">Status:</td>' + '<td id="value">' + obj1.outerHTML + '</td>' + '</tr>' +
                                '<tr>' + '<td id="header">Groups:</td>' + '<td id="value">' + GroupName + '</td>' + '</tr></table>';
                            obj2.innerHTML = Helptext;
                        }
                        error: function(errormsg) {
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(errormsg.responseXML));
                        }
                    });

                }

            });
</script>

        <style type = "text/css" > a.URL {
     position: relative;
     display: inline;
}
 a.URL .tooltiptext {
     position: absolute;
     width:200px;
     color: #FFFFFF;
     background: #737373;
     border: 2px solid #000000;
     text-align: left;
     visibility: hidden;
     border-radius: 6px;
     z-index: 1;
     top: -45px;
     left: 110%;
     padding: 5px 0;
}
 a.URL .tooltiptext:before {
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     right: 100%;
     margin-top: -12px;
     width: 0;
     height: 0;
     border-right: 12px solid #000000;
     border-top: 12px solid transparent;
     border-bottom: 12px solid transparent;
}
 a.URL .tooltiptext:after {
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     right: 100%;
     margin-top: -8px;
     width: 0;
     height: 0;
     border-right: 8px solid #737373;
     border-top: 8px solid transparent;
     border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
}
 .URL:hover .tooltiptext {
     visibility: visible;
}
 </style>
```

Comment: I have achieved this myself.  I replaced the following lines in .tooltiptext and it made the miracle top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this myself. I replaced the following lines in .tooltiptext and it made the miracle.

top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);